# How can I use clearInterval to stop my function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I currently have a function that sequences through a number of images using setInterval, changing the opacity from 0 to 1, however I need the interval to clear once it's looped through all the images. At the moment, once it's been through all the images the function breaks.

// startImageSequence Function

```
startImageSequence() {
    let sequence_frames = document.querySelectorAll('.sequenceImage').length;
    let sequence_current_frame = 0;

    setInterval(function(){
        let seqimgs = document.querySelectorAll('.sequenceImage');
      seqimgs[sequence_current_frame].style.opacity = 0;

        sequence_current_frame++;
        if(sequence_current_frame > sequence_frames) {
        let sequence_current_frame = 0;
        clearInterval();
      }

        seqimgs[sequence_current_frame].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 50);
  }
```

// images

```
<img src="..." class="sequenceImage" />
<img src="..." class="sequenceImage" />
<img src="..." class="sequenceImage" />
<img src="..." class="sequenceImage" />
<img src="..." class="sequenceImage" />
...
```

Comment: Have you done any reading at all about CSS animations?  Have you tried any pure CSS animations?  Plus, nobody could really help you without seeing a full working example that you want to emulate including relevant HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the handle to the interval and then call clearInterval with it.

Try this:

```
startImageSequence() {
   let sequence_frames = document.querySelectorAll('.sequenceImage').length;
   let sequence_current_frame = 0;
   let intervalHandle;
   intervalHandle=  setInterval(function(){
      let seqimgs = document.querySelectorAll('.sequenceImage');
      seqimgs[sequence_current_frame].style.opacity = 0;

      sequence_current_frame++;
      if(sequence_current_frame >= sequence_frames) {
       sequence_current_frame = 0; // removed the let
       clearInterval(intervalHandle);
     }

      seqimgs[sequence_current_frame].style.opacity = 1;
  }, 50);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for this, I've tried this however I'm receiving the following error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: I’m doing this on a phone so I’m winging it here. I made a change to >= in the if statement prior to the clearInterval. The old code looks like it was going to the length of your array, which would probably lead to an undefined object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use clearInterval to stop you function using this technique:

```
function startImageSequence() {
    let sequence_frames = document.querySelectorAll('.sequenceImage').length;
    let sequence_current_frame = 0;

   var clear =  setInterval(function(){
        let seqimgs = document.querySelectorAll('.sequenceImage');
      seqimgs[sequence_current_frame].style.opacity = 0;

        sequence_current_frame++;

        if(sequence_current_frame > sequence_frames) {
            let sequence_current_frame = 0;
            clearInterval(this);
        }

        seqimgs[sequence_current_frame].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 50);
}
```

You just need to store your setInterval function in a specific variable and then use this variable in clearInterval to define which interval is going to stop. 
 I hope you will find it helpful.